# Data Binding not working in WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I've been trying to get a handle on data binding, and I'm having trouble making it work.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm using VS2012 and programming in WPF/vb.net.  I've got an xaml UI, a class to update the properties, and module running my main loop. I'm trying to update a textblock in the UI based on dynamic data from the module.

Here's the important XAML from the UI:

```
<Page x:Class="pPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BMI_WPF_v1"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Title="BMI">

<Page.Resources>
    <local:clsItemGUI x:Key="clsitemgui" />
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="p_force" Text="{Binding Path=Force, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Here's what I'm calling in my main module to attempt to update the GUI:

```
Dim bmiUI As New clsItemGUI
bmiUI.UpdateForce(currentForce)
```

And here's the class that is meant to update the GUI:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class clsItemGUI
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private ForceValue As Double

Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateForce(ByVal inputForce As String)
    Me.ForceValue = inputForce
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Property Force() As Double
    Get
        Return ForceValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        ForceValue = value
        OnPropertyChanged("Force")
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub

End Class
```

It looks like I'm updating ForceValue, but that isn't triggering an update on the UI.  Obviously I'm missing something stupid, but I haven't stumbled on the right resource, yet.

Comment: I think you need to set your class to the page data context instead of resource

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I had done that?  Can you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this

add datacontext under page resources

```
<Page.DataContext>

  <local:clsItemGUI/>

</Page.DataContext>
```

(with mode=TwoWay)

```
<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="p_force" Text="{Binding Path=Force, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, J King.  Now the textblock reads "0" (where it used to be blank), but it still doesn't update.  I'm stepping through the code and I can see that I'm passing my force variable into Me.ForceValue.  However, my two breakpoints at:
    Return ForceValue 
and
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))

...are never reached.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign `DataContext` to root layout (in my example it's `Grid`):

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource clsitemgui}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="p_force" Text="{Binding Path=Force, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />   
    <Button x:Name="btn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Change" Click="Button_Click" />        
</Grid>
```

or you can set `Source` property when you binding, like this:

```
<TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="p_force" Text="{Binding Path=Force, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You have also error in `UpdateForce` method, you should assign new value to `Force` property not to `ForceValue` field. When you assign this value to field `OnPropertyChanged` it's not invoked.

```
Public Class clsItemGUI
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private ForceValue As Double

    Sub New()
        Force = 2.5
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateForce(ByVal inputForce As Double)
        Me.Force = inputForce
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Property Force() As Double
        Get
            Return ForceValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            ForceValue = value
            OnPropertyChanged("Force")
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

End Class
```

When you update you should do that on the current object which you assign as a `DataContext` so you should cast this object and invoke `UpdateForce` function on it:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim dt As clsItemGUI
    dt = CType(btn.DataContext, clsItemGUI)
    dt.UpdateForce(5.2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Kmatyaszek, I tried both of these changes, but my UI is still not updating.  I am, however, now hitting the breakpoint on "Return ForceValue" -- only once, when I first load the program (before the UI has come up).

Comment: @gadget00 check my answer again :)

Comment: ah!  Now we're cookin with gas.  Now as I step through the code, I hit the UpdateForce function, which triggers the Force() property function and, then, the OnPropertyChanged Function.  However, it's still not updating the UI.  My UI now reads 2.5, constantly.

Comment: I believe the UI is just frozen, now... but it should be running on it's own thread, no?  Back in Windows Forms (where I'm more comfortable) I would have thrown in an Application.DoEvents(), but I understand that's no longer necessary.

Comment: @gadget00 I created for you simple example, you can download it here: http://sdrv.ms/116B6Op

Comment: Thanks very much!  But how do I update it from my main loop, instead of the button?

Comment: I built in a background thread and the UI now functions while the main loop is updating the force, but the textblock still isn't being updated.  I can seen the Set and PropertyChanged functions being called.  What am I missing?

Comment: @gadget00 can you show me code (main loop) where you update that property?

Comment: I believe the problem is that I'm somehow referencing two instances of the same class.  When the UI starts, the New() function (that sets Force = 2.5) is called.  Then, New() is called again when I call "Dim bmiUI As New clsItemGUI" in the main loop.

Comment: @gadget00 you must copy and paste code from `Button_Click` event handler to your main loop. And after that you can invoke `UpdateForce` on the right object.

Comment: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." -- I get that when I try to reference anything in my XAML.

Comment: I'm just working in the code you provided, now.  I've created a simple Module, and I've got a main function that runs when you click the button.  I've moved your original button code into the main function, but the button is not referenceable.

If I ever manage to fix this problem, I'd love to figure out how to run the main function in a never-ending loop, and update the UI constantly.  I'm not sure how to deal with the threading, there.